# How to realize the Floating snow effect in a page of app?

Tags: android, 2d

How to add the Floating snow effect in an activity which has done?

I use Canvas and 2D to make the Floating snow effect. But I use main.xml in my home page. I use

```
http://ask.csdn.net/questions/1246
```

But I check online the code is

```
PetalView pv = new PetalView(this);
setContentView(pv);
```

How to mix the two views together?

How to make the effect on the top and do not affect the operation of this activity page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with a `FrameLayout` (it allows you to stack views):

```
    FrameLayout fl = new FrameLayout(this);        
    FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = new 
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
```

Add your xml:

```
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    View mainView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main, null);
    fl.addView(mainView);
```

Add your dynamic view with a transparent background:

```
    PetalView pv = new PetalView(this);
    pv.setBackgroundColor(0x00000000);
    fl.addView(pv);

    setContentView(fl);
```